# Consider the signature with just one function symbol, $\times$, and constants 0 and 1.

Tags: logic, model-theory

Consider the signature with just one function symbol, $\times$, and constants 0 and 1.

1. M1 is the usual integers $Z$ with the usual interpretations of $\times$, 0,
   and 1.
2. M2 is the usual real numbers $R$ with the usual interpretations of $\times$
   , 0, and 1.
3. M3 is the usual complex numbers $C$ with the usual interpretations
   of $\times$, 0, and 1.

Question:

- Find a sentence $\sigma$ holds for M1 but not for M2 or M3
- Find a sentence $\gamma$ holds for M2 but not for M1 or M3
- Find a sentence $\phi$ holds for M3 but not for M1 or M2

I stuck with this question for a while. I really need a hint to start with. Thank you.

Comment: Can you find an integer $a$ such that $a{\,\times\,}a = 2$? How abut real number $a$ with that property? Can you find a real number $a$ such that $a{\,\times\,}a = -1$? How about a complex number with that property?

Comment: But how can I get 2 since there are only ×,0,1 I can use with.

Comment: Right you are! Forget that comment. But look at my answer, just posted.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** For any given, fixed, natural number $n$, what numbers are expressible as $a^n$? Does it change if $a$ is real, complex, or an integer?

Comment: The OP can't quantify over the exponent $n$ in $a^n$. Fortunately, just looking at $n = 3$ will do.

Comment: @RobArthan Reworded slightly to make it clearer that I only wanted OP to consider one $n$ at a time.

Answer (score 2):

A sentence that holds in $M_1$, but not in $M_2$ or $M_3$:

$$a{\,\times\,}b=1 \rightarrow a = b$$

A sentence that holds in $M_2$, but not in $M_1$ or $M_3$:

$$
{\large(}
(a{\,\times\,}(a{\,\times\,}a))
=
(b{\,\times\,}(b{\,\times\,}b){\large)}
{\large)}
\rightarrow a=b)
\land 
{\large(}
\forall a,\exists b\,
((b{\,\times\,}(b{\,\times\,}b))=a)
{\large)}
$$

A sentence that holds in $M_3$, but not in $M_1$ or $M_2$:

$$\forall a, \exists b\,{\large(}b{\,\times\,}b=a{\large)}$$

Comment: I suspect the OP's integers can be negative, so your first "sentence" won't work. The idea behind your second sentence works for all three questions: in $\Bbb{Z}$ some numbers have no cube roots, in $\Bbb{R}$ every number has exactly one cube root and in $\Bbb{C}$ every non-zero number has three cube roots.

Comment: @RobArthan: There's no problem with the first sentence. In $\mathbb{Z}$, if $a \times b=1$ then either $a=b=1$ or $a=b=-1$; in either case, we have $a=b$. Your characterisation in terms of cube roots is nice, though, since it doesn't even require a constant symbol $1$, only a binary function symbol $\times$.

Comment: Sure. Apologies about my brainstorm about your first sentence.